# NPM package.json convert * asterisk to version

Tags: npm, package.json

I have a package.json from my template with several dependencies.
If I want to create a new project, I use my template.
But how to convert all `*` (asterisk sign / latest version) to a fixed version which is downloaded from npm. `npm install --save` does not work.

Before npm install (template package.json)

```js
"devDependencies": {
  "one": "*",
  "two": "*",
  "three": "*"
}
```

should convert to following by `npm i --save`.

```js
"devDependencies": {
  "one": "1.0.0",
  "two": "2.0.0",
  "three": "3.0.0"
}
```

How to overwrite the version string?

Comment: Only way found so far is the usual: `npm i one@*` or `npm i one@latest`. Do it for every package with a custom script (JSON parsing, etc.). I am afraid, this is the only solution for current versions - happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies)

(*) --> Matches any version

("") --> (just an empty string) Same as *

The workaround of this issue is [shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap)(Read documentation for further information). You can use this command `npm shrinkwrap`.That creats a npm-shrinkwrap.json file. When you run the command,You get the following comments on console (**npm notice package-lock.json has been renamed to npm-shrinkwrap.json. npm-shrinkwrap.json will be used for future installations.**). And that will gave the updated package version whatever you have in package.json.

Comment: This not really a solution to the problem. Can you give a detailed example? I have a template package.json "package": "*" and after installation i want  "package": "^1.0.0"

Comment: @kombye I already provided a link in the solution. And the same thing I have written it. I think you didn't check it. And it's not any random link.

Please check this out: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm list --depth=0` to see what versions were installed by installing 'latest' from your template. You should get something like this:

```
├── @angular-devkit/architect@0.1501.1
├── @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.1.1
├── @angular-eslint/builder@15.2.0
```

Copy, modify and paste output into your package.json. Then you should probably remove node_modules and check if running `npm ci` works properly.

Notes:

1. This is how you should specify wanted versions in package.json:

```
"react": "^16.0.0" // carat: allow 16.1.0
"react": "~16.0.0" // tilde: allow 16.0.1
"react": "16.0.0" // exact: only 16.0.0
```

2. If your template is fairly complicated, it is highly unlikly that such workflow would be convenient. I would advise having specific versions in the template carefully combined, so that they work. Then, once every couple of months, you should (again, carefully) updgrade libraries in your template. Otherwise, sooner or later you are going to install two latest version of some conflicting pakages.